# Get the first value that is not 0 in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
   |    A   |    B   |
---|--------|--------|---------
1  |    0   |   500  |
2  |    0   |        |
3  |    0   |        |
4  |  500   |        |
5  |  400   |        |
6  |    0   |        |
7  |  700   |        |
8  |  300   |        |
9  |        |        |
```

---

In `Cell B1` I want to display the first value that is `<> 0` in the `Column A`. 
(in this example it would be 500)

I tried to go with something like this but could not make it work:

```
B1 =LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A8<>0),A1:A8)
```

How do I need to modify the formula to get the needed result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try `FILTER()`.

```
=@FILTER(A:A,A:A>0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works. I know I was not asking this in the question but how do I need to change your formula to also make it work when instead of 0 there is =NA() in the cells?

Comment: May be `=@FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")` if it is error value then `=@FILTER(A:A,IFNA(A:A))`

Comment: Both solutions are not working on my side so for the situation with =NV() so in this case I will go with =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A<>0,),0))

Comment: This works, but I don't know if it is best practice: =@FILTER(FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISERROR(A:A)));FILTER(A:A;NOT(ISERROR(A:A)))<>0)

Answer (score 1):

Index and Match will find the next non 0 in a column

```
=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A:A<>0,),0))
```